# Compare values in numpy array and Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an array of type `numpy.ndarray` and pandas DataFrame and need a way to compare each value to each other.

Below is one of the ways I've tried to do it. I've also used `pd.get(labels)` to pull the values out and was returned `None`. `y_test` is a pandas DataFrame and `preds` is a numpy array of predictions.

Tried converting both of them to lists as well as numpy arrays for comparison:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=2000)

preds = model.predict(x_test)
preds[preds>=0.5] = 1
preds[preds<0.5] = 0
print(type(preds))
print(y_test.get('labels'))
total = 0
for i in range(len(preds)):
    if int(preds[i]) == y_test[i]:
        total = total + 1
```

This is what I am getting - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable - KeyError: 0

Answer (score 1):

So if y_test is a dataframe, then you can just ask for the values like this to get a numpy array:

```
y_test_array = y_test["labels"].values
```

Then print this out to know how many items are equal:

```
sum(y_test_array == preds)# number of items with same value
sum(y_test_array == preds)/len(preds)# %
```

I hope is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted to find the performance of your model so just use `.evaluate()` method, I am assuming that you are using a keras model here.

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=2000)

score= model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```